# Send string parameter to controller using AJAX call for jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a ajax call that goes like

```
this.GetTransactionsInputToday = function () {
             var status="complete"
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Management/function1',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: status,
                 type: 'GET',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     return result;
                 }
             });
         }
```

I have also tried doing like this

```
this.GetTransactionsInputToday = function () {
             var status="complete"; 
              $.ajax({
                     url: '/Management/function1/' + status,
                     type: 'GET',
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (result) {
                         return result;
                     }
                 });
             }
```

I have a controller function in my management controller class

```
public JsonResult function1(string status)
{
Some code here.. 
}
```

The issue is that every time function1 is called teh value of status comes as null.
CAn any one please let me know where am I going wrong??

Comment: please change the title because the question is above JOSNstring not simple string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to define name for the data you sending  `data: {'status': status}`:

```
this.GetTransactionsInputToday = function () {
    var status="complete"
    var r = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Management/function1',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {'status': status},
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            r = result;
        }
    });

    return r;
};
```

Also your `this.GetTransactionsInputToday` will not return result as you expected. The success handler of ajax function gets called asynchronously. So your `return r` statement will return **''** as it gets called before the Ajax request gets completed.

Comment: Is there a way to achive this: func = 'getDetails'; data = 'loads of data'; and then in $.ajax({ ... data: { func : data }. ? now it sends string named func so in php is $_POST['func'], i want to send string content as name to php not 'func' but $_POST['getDetails']. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You might construct the json parameter wrongly.

using json: 
`data: "{'prop1': '" + value1+ "'}"`

```
$.ajax({
             url: '/Management/function1',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: "{'prop1': '" + value1+ "'}",
             type: 'GET',
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                 return result;
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable outside the ajax function and then return it, this way its in the right scope. Also in order to get an immediate value you need to make this ajax call synchronous.

```
this.GetTransactionsInputToday = function () {
    var status = "complete";
    var r = '';

    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url: '/Management/function1',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {'status' : status},
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            r = result;
        }
    });

    return r;
};
```